# Q: Proposing tags that do not have questions yet?

Tags: discussion, tags

After looking at the new tags section the other day I saw a new tag about airflow.  Having dealt with several cooling and airflow issues in server rooms and datacenter environments I added the tag to my highlighted tags.

After adding that tag I thought I would look for some synonyms that might also be relevant, like [hvac] and [cooling], only to discover that they do not yet exist.

While I do not have specific question about either tag right now, it seems that some new tags do have the potential to inspire questions about specific topics, which may be useful in cases where users have asked broad sweeping questions.

Is there some mechanism for submitting new tags, ideally with at least an excerpt without a specific question in the hopes of inspiring other questions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To create a new tag, either:

- Add it as a tag on a *new* question, or
- Edit an *existing* question to include the new tag.

In either case, [creating a new tag](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/create-tags) requires 300 reputation.

Once the tag is created this way, you can then edit it to include an excerpt and tag wiki entry.

Answer (score 2):

One thing to bear in mind is that tags not attached to questions are automagically deleted by the system. If you do create new tags and put some effort into their wikis then ensure that they are attached to suitable questions.